# Android AdMob Empty Banner

Tags: android, admob, banner

I'm just trying to display a banner in my app with this code:

XML File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00BFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
<!--Put form controls here-->

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createevent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/createSportEvent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/joinevent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/joinSportEvent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
         />

<!--       <TextView -->
<!--           android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
<!--           android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<!--           android:gravity="center" -->
<!--           android:text="@string/welcome" -->
<!--           android:textColor="#FFFFFF" -->
<!--           android:textSize="30sp" -->
<!--           android:layout_marginTop="60dp" /> -->



    </LinearLayout>  

  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="4" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4655928626183886/8875858459"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA file:

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("005d82a31685xxxx");  
    adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

I have google-play-services.jar in my Java_Buid_Path.

and in my Android_Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

I have added in adMob website a banner to my mobile application to get the adUnitId.

I don't understand why there is no banner displayed.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several reasons for that issue.

To find out what exactly is causing the problem start your `Activity` and filter `Logcat` for "ads".

It will tell you what is causing the problem.

A really common mistake beside the wrong `ad-unit-id` is if there isn't enough space to display the `banner` regarding the height. Make sure you have enough space. And please give `Update` what's in the `LogCat`.

But i can't say more without your filtered logcat and your XML..

Comment: Yes, this is a good place to start.  Also, though it may seem obvious, make sure your device is connected to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My device is connected to the internet.     My logcat:

Comment: 01-11 23:43:32.399: I/Ads(20408): Ad closing.
01-11 23:43:35.009: I/Ads(20408): Starting ad request.
01-11 23:43:35.010: I/Ads(20408): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("C156FAF59725453A0DXXXXXX) to get test ads on this device.
01-11 23:43:38.600: I/Ads(20408): Ad finished loading.
01-11 23:43:38.600: D/(20408): onAdLoaded
01-11 23:43:38.645: I/Ads(20408): Ad opening.
01-11 23:43:41.660: I/Ads(20408): Ad closing.

Comment: I have tried to adjust the height to be sure that there is enough space but without success. You can see my XML file edited. On the same screen (not the same activity), i have a navigation drawer with an interstitial ad. I have tried to remove the interstitial but the banner still doesn't work..

Comment: If a remove the interstitial ad, there is nothing in logcat concerning ads.